# Is pg_catalog is available for aws redshift data-share consumer

Tags: redshift

I just started to read about aws redshift [data-sharing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/concepts.html) feature. And I wonder if Data consumers has access to "pg_catalog"/INFOMATION_SCHEMA  of tables that exposed to them?

(the goal is that a data consumers will be able get a list of columns by table name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end found view that contain this information - [SVV_ALL_COLUMNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_ALL_COLUMNS.html)